# Why is my function plotting incorrectly when using sympy.plotting.plot?

Tags: python, function, plot, sympy

I am using sympy.plotting.plot to plot my function but, it shows me a different graph then when I plot the same function in my graphic calculator.

My code is:

```
def S(t):
    return (10*sympy.E**(t/12)*((sympy.sin((sympy.pi*t)/24))**2))
sympy.plotting.plot(S(t), xlim=[0,24])
```

Also, when I just do this,

```
sympy.plotting.plot(10*sympy.E**(t/12)*((sympy.sin((sympy.pi*t)/24))**2), xlim=[0,24])
```

it shows a different graph. In my calculator the function has a maximum at approximately t=14 while in python, the graph stops at t=10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sympy plot](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot.plot) function takes a second argument to specify the range to draw on, it's a tuple of `(symbol,min,max)`, while `xlim` is used to limit the screen after the plot is drawn, it doesn't affect what's being drawn, ie: you can still move the plot to override xlim.

```py
import sympy
t = sympy.sympify('t')
sympy.plotting.plot(10*sympy.E**(t/12)*((sympy.sin((sympy.pi*t)/24))**2),(t,0,24))
```

[image]